# Salt state: can I decide the order in which packages are installed?

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following state:

```
# windows.sls

windows:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - python2_x64
      - vcforpython27
```

When executing `salt -G 'os:Windows' state.highstate`, these packages are installed in a different order than specified in the sls file. The order which will be used can be previewed by running `salt -G 'os:Windows' state.highstate test=true`.

How can I force the order in which packages are going to be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward way would be:

```
python2_x64:
  pkg.installed

vcforpython27:
  pkg.installed

# continue for all other packages ...
```

Saltstack will use the order specified in the file to install the packages.

Comment: Also, the [order option](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/ordering.html#the-order-option) can be used. That page also explains how you can skip ordering and use "requires" to decide which packages needs to be installed prior to others etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use require or onlyif option:

```
foo:
  pkg.installed:
    - require:
      - bar
 foo:
  pkg.installed:
    - onlyif:
      - bar
```